Is it OK to use the same transfer pump for gear oil and engine oil?
I'm wondering if the small amount of cross-contamination will cause any issues.
In my case, I'm using a syringe-style pump to fill an outboard engine's gear oil + engine oil.

It shouldn't cause you any issues. If you are worried about it, you can lessen the amount of cross-contamination by cleaning the syringe between usages. Spray it out with some brake/carb cleaner and call it a day.
